# undefined Number_to_currency inside a helper (are helpers for views or controllers?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, view-helpers

I have a helper for my view, but get an undefined method "number_to_currency" when I try the `cost_dollar` method.

## app/helpers/books_helper.rb

```
Module BooksHelper
  require 'action_view'
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper 

  def cost_dollar
   @book.cost.number_to_currency
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use number_to_currency(value) not value.number_to_currency

```
  def cost_dollar
   number_to_currency(@book.cost)
  end
```